# Dropdown menu works with ids but not classes

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Recently I decided to add a second drop down menu to my navigation. Originally there was only one drop down so I used an id attribute to mark it. When adding the second one I thought it was going to be as simple as changing the id to a class attribute and changing the appropriate selectors in the CSS file. However that does not appear to be the case. As you can see in the examples below the version with class attributes doesn't work properly when moused over while the exact same navigation which uses two id attributes for the drop downs works as intended.

I assume this might have something to do with the order of the CSS rules.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5d24upa/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="menuholder">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li class="menumem"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="menumem"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="submenutop"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenubottom"><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenutop"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 4</a></li>
                <li class="submenubottom"><a href="#">SubItem 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menumem"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.submenu{
display:none;
list-style:none;
width:19%
}

#menuholder ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block
}


#mainmenu{
list-style:none;
display:inline-table;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
font-size:20px
}

#mainmenu li{
    float:left;
    background:#000000;
    width:19%
}
    #mainmenu li:hover{
        background:#FF0000;
    }
        #mainmenu li:hover a{
            color:#FFFFFF
        }

    #mainmenu li a{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none
    }


.submenu{
    padding:0;
    position:absolute

}

    .submenu li{ 
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background:#000000
    }
        .submenu li a{
            width:100%;

        }
        .submenu li:hover{
            background:#FF0000
        }
            .submenu li a:hover{
                color:#FFFFFF
            }

.menumem{
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px
}
.submenutop{
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
    border-radius:15px 15px 0 0
}

.submenubottom{
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
    border-radius:0 0 15px 15px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1n5f7dh1/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="menuholder">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li class="menumem"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="menumem"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="submenutop"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul id="submenu2">
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenubottom"><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenutop"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <ul id="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem 4</a></li>
                <li class="submenubottom"><a href="#">SubItem 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menumem"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#submenu,#submenu2{
display:none;
list-style:none;
width:19%
}

#menuholder ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block
}


#mainmenu{
list-style:none;
display:inline-table;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
font-size:20px
}

#mainmenu li{
    float:left;
    background:#000000;
    width:19%
}
    #mainmenu li:hover{
        background:#FF0000;
    }
        #mainmenu li:hover a{
            color:#FFFFFF
        }

    #mainmenu li a{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none
    }


#submenu,#submenu2{
    padding:0;
    position:absolute

}

    #submenu li,#submenu2 li{ 
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background:#000000
    }
        #submenu li a,#submenu2 li a{
            width:100%;

        }
        #submenu li:hover,#submenu2 li:hover{
            background:#FF0000
        }
            #submenu li a:hover,#submenu2 li a:hover{
                color:#FFFFFF
            }

.menumem{
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px
}
.submenutop{
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;
    border-radius:15px 15px 0 0
}

.submenubottom{
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
    border-radius:0 0 15px 15px
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ul containing the dropdown is 100% of its parent, but the li's inside it are 19%. That comes from your top-level `#mainmenu li` rule, which is overriding `.submenu li`. You could hack it by setting `.submenu li`'s `width:100%!important;`, as others have indicated, but this hurts readability later, when you will be trying to troubleshoot more complicated cascades.

CSS chooses what it considers the most specific rule for each attribute. **ID is more specific than class**, even though the class is on an element closer to the one you want to change.

Turn .submenu li into **#mainmenu .submenu li**, and the lower-level dropdown rules will take precedence.

```
#mainmenu .submenu li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works now. I was never aware that IDs are considered more important than classes when it came to CSS. It's also nice to have it work without !important hacks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your `#mainmenu li` css property overriding the properties of your `.submenu li` just do the following changes to your `.submenu li`.

```
.submenu li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;/*Changed*/
    background: #000000 !important; /*Changed*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e5d24upa/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I prefer MBerka's solution. It seems much better from a maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the width parameter in `.submenu` from `width:19%` to `width:100%`.
Second you need to add to `.submenu li` a `clear:both` parameter.

Suggestion:
If you are using % for defining the width, you need to know that the width, padding and margin parameters add up. So if you want your element to fill in 100% without overflowing the above mentioned parameters should add up to 100%
Ex:

```
.myClass {
    width:92%;
    padding:2%;
    margin:2%;
}
```

Total width of an element = width + ( 2 * padding ) + ( 2 * margin )

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll make sure to check them out. :)